# How do you reject a string if preceded by another string using standard POSIX regex?

Tags: regex, sitescope

I have a regex which finds errors in a log for me:

```
/(exception|error)/i
```

This works, except that I do not want to be alerted when the following occurs, which I expect to happen:

```
DD/MM/YYYY 10:20pm: Read exception encountered
```

How do I specifically reject the 'Read exception encountered' string?  I'm trying to use the ?! operator, but failing:

```
/(?!Read exception encountered)(exception|error)/i
```

The above still matches the string I want to exclude.

**UPDATE:**
After experimenting with the negative lookbehind and lookahead solutions below, I have discovered that SiteScope supports only basic POSIX regex features, not extended features.  Is a solution possible using only basic POSIX regex features?

Comment: Which programming language?

Comment: I'm not sure.  I'm using SiteScope.  Standard Regex?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use "Negative Lookbehind" (if it's supported by your regex engine.)  effectively you say "I want to match X patern, as long as this other pattern does NOT preceed it."

In your example, it looks like this:

```
/(?<!read )(exception|error)/i
```

see more about "lookaround" features [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

Comment: The expression `(?<!read )(exception|error)` could get hung up on possible edge cases like `Thread exception while running report`

Comment: It appears that SiteScope does not support Negative Lookbehind, but still +1 for your assistance - this is a likely solution for others who find this question.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to reject the entire string if the sub-string `Read exception encountered` is in the string, then I would simply use a negative look ahead which is supported by most languages.

`^(?![^\r\n]*?\bRead exception encountered\b)[^\r\n]*?(exception|error)`

Live example: http://www.rubular.com/r/CV7P9huVsI

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this
/([^R][^e][^a][^d]) (exception|error)/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the "beginning of line" character is what you need. 
I am assuming every line of the log has either "exception" or "error".
So you could match for

```
/^(RegexpForDateTimeGoesHere)(exception|error)/i
```

This will match on every exception or error message which is directly following the timestamp. If there is a "Read" between the timestamp and (exception|error) it will not match.

Comment: I do not know that the exception|error will directly follow the timestamp.  So this would fail if the message was "(timestamp): Oh hell everything is on fire due to an error"